# q Query: creating grid from a table

Tags: kdb, q-query

I have written a function that wraps a q query that returns me a table with three columns - c1,c2 and vals. How do I create a grid (2D array) such that I have c1 as x axis, c2 as y axis and values in the corresponding cells. For example, if one of the row in the table is c1:A c2:B value:100, I want to display A on x axis, B on y axis and 100 in the cell corresponding to (A,B).

I appreciate your help.

Input:
`_c1_`¦`_c2_`¦vals
===============-
 `_A_`¦`_B_`¦ 100
 `_A_`¦`_Y_`¦ 110
 `_X_`¦`_Y_`¦ 120
 `_X_`¦`_T_`¦ 220

Output:
`_ _`¦`_B_`¦`_Y_`¦`_T_`¦
===============-
`_A_`¦100¦ 110¦000¦
`_X_`¦000¦ 120¦220¦

Apologize for bad formatting, I'm not sure how to create a proper table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to pivot your resultant table:

```
q)tt:flip`c1`c2`vals!(`a`a`x`x;`b`y`y`t;100 200 300 400)
q)tt
c1 c2 vals
----------
a  b  100
a  y  200
x  y  300
x  t  400
q)0^exec (distinct tt`c2)#c2!vals by c1:c1 from tt
c1| b   y   t
--| -----------
a | 100 200 0
x | 0   300 400
```

You can look at [Pivot Table](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/pivoting-tables/) for more information.